# Is the number of Facebook like buttons in a single page limited?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, limit, lazy-loading

Consider a lazy-loading gallery where 10-15 images are shown. Each image has a [Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) below it, and scrolling down the gallery potentially lazy-loads hundreds of images.

Each image is clickable, and has its own url (a-la `http://gallery.example.com?imageId=1234`). The URL in the Like button is the image URL.

[image]

According to the manual, each like button is a `div`:

```
<div class="fb-like" 
    data-href="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
    data-layout="standard" 
    data-action="like" 
    data-show-faces="true">
</div>
```

**Is there a limit to the number of like buttons I can put in the same page?**

Comment: This really should not have been migrated to SO